# Undefined reference error when I try to call compiled NASM function from C program

Tags: c, linux, gcc, nasm, undefined-reference

I have a c program, to optimize this program I have tried this:

1. compile the most heavy method (named *my_method*) separately
2. disassembly the compiled method
3. editing the assembly code generated from the compiler to optimize this
4. compile edited and optimized assembly code with NASM compiler

the original c method has this signature

```
float **my_method(int m, int n, float **MatrixA, float **VectorB){
   //method boby
}
```

**The problem:**
How to call the compiled optimized "NASMed" version of the method from C?

I have tried to declare this at the beginning of the c file

```
extern float **my_method(int m, int n, float **MatrixA, float **VectorB);
```

but when I try to call the method in c for example with

```
float **res= mymethod(rows, columns, matrix1, vect);
```

GCC returns me this error: 
***Undefined reference to my_method***

the compiled assembly file is named `my_method.o` my c file is named `my_program.c`

I have tried to compile with `gcc my_program.c`

Comment: This a linker error. What linker options do you use?

Comment: @alk surely I'm missing something. I have compiled simply with the classic command `gcc -o1 -s myfile.c` without specify any linker option

Comment: You need to tell gcc about the my_method.o file so it can be included at link time.

Comment: could you describe the exactly procedure? so I could fix my problem and accept the answer. thanks

Comment: `-o1`  was meant to be `-O1`, wasn't it?

Comment: @alk no is an optimization flag

Comment: Optimisation is ordered with a captialised `O`! The small `o`  defiens the name of the output file to be generated. `-o1` in your case would create the final executbale with the name `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to use something like

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic my_program.c -o my_program my_method.o
```

with `my_method.o` being the result of the NASM compilation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  what is the meaning of -Wall -Wextra and -pediandic ?

Comment: Those are options to enable warnings. For more on this please read here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html @AndreaF

Comment: I get the error `et not enabled"
 # error "SSE instruction set not enabled"
`
If I add the flag `-march=native` to enable istruction set of the current CPU, I get again `Undefined reference to my_method`

Comment: You can look up what `my_method.o` exports using `objdump`.